# Does iterating over ConcurrentHashMap in Java cause blocking

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I understand that we can iterate over a ConcurrentHashMap on one thread while another thread is writing a particular segment on the map.

In the case where the iterator is accessing a segment that is being written to by another thread, does the iterator block, or is it reading from a clone of the segment?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/how-concurrenthashmap-works-internally-in-java

Comment: @Sebastian Incorrect. Some operations still block.

Comment: yes @Sebastian blocking does happen, this is a nice read https://dzone.com/articles/how-concurrenthashmap-works-internally-in-java

Comment: @Vihar, so in the scenario I have described, it would block right? Sorry, the article does not explicitly say this

Comment: **Read the documentation**. The second paragraph of the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) answers the questions: *"Retrieval operations (including get) **generally do not block**, so may overlap with update operations ... ... **Iterators**, Spliterators and Enumerations return elements **reflecting the state of the hash table at some point** at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration."*

Comment: If you closely look at the code blocks in the doc, there is no cloning/duplication of data, it will just read whatever is present in the Map

Comment: So there is no cloning sure. However, if a segment is locked for write, how would it be accessed for a read without a block?

Comment: You saw they use synchronized blocks. For read only stuff it looks like they're ok with volatile variables and [AtomicReferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html).